How can I stop Chromium run by Playwright from stealing focus?
I have a playwright script on my Ubuntu 24 Gnome system.  Playwright is running chromium in headed mode because it's more informative while developing.  When a new tab opens, focus is stolen from whatever window I was working in.  This is annoying because my workflow is to do other things while monitoring Playwright's progress.
I've tried minimizing the window, but that seems to halt running of the script, and it eventually times out on interactions with the page as though those elements aren't visible.  For what it's worth, puppeteer has always had the exact same problem, including under Cinnamon.
Is there anything I can do?

There's a window position arg, you can try putting it off your screen

According to what looks like a Playwright dev from this similar question thread from github, headed mode windows will always steal focus.
However, while developing and monitoring progress disabling parallelism is most likely the best move. That way each test will run in a row and the next one wont start until the previous is finished. You can disable parallelism by limiting the number of playwright workers to 1, either in the command line options:
npx playwright test --workers=1

Or in the config file, or a test file:
disable parallelism Playwright
Otherwise if you want to keep the previous test tab in front when a new one opens, you can use Playwright's page.bringToFront() on the previous tab which will focus it or 'bring it to the front'. However this will still result in the focus from your work window being stolen.
bringToFront() Documentation
